# Null regex not allowed Missing block

Tags: raku

Got this simple grammar:

```
grammar H1 {
    token TOP { <h1> }
    token h1 { \#  }
}
```

Results in: `Null regex not allowed Missing block`

Google turns up next to nothing on it.

Comment: With `#`, you start a [comment](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_readability:_whitespace_and_comments) in the token; then your token is effectively ``\`` but you don't escape anything with it, hence the error(s).

Comment: See also [`regex { \# }` doesn't parse](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4387).

Comment: "Null regex not allowed Missing block" That's two error messages without a newline between them. In other words, the parser is well and truly confused!

Answer (score 4):

Still not sure why escaping doesn't work, but this does:

```
grammar H1 {
    token TOP { <h1> }
    token h1 { '#'  }
}
```

Comment: Escaping does not work for certain characters in regexen. You need to quote them.